# VBA excel finding the statistical mode of a collection

Tags: vba, collections

So I'm trying to analysis some data in Excel and having some trouble finding the most frequent numbers. I have an unknown number of locations which can have an unknown number of donations. For example

- Brantford $50.00
- Brantford $25.00
- Brantford $50.00
- Windsor   $200.00
- Quebec    $25.00
- Quebec    $100.00
- Quebec    $50.00
- Quebec    $50.00
- Quebec    $25.00
- Quebec    $50.00
- Quebec    $50.00
- Quebec    $25.00
- Quebec    $100.00
- Quebec    $40.00
- Windsor   $140.00
- Windsor   $20.00
- Windsor   $20.00

So I need to use VBA to find for each location the count, sum, mean and mode (has to be done through VBA, can't just write instructions on how to do this using advanced filters/pivot tables :().

So right now using VBA I have a dictionary object that stores the location name as a key and each donation in a collection. Using the count of the collection I have the count, can easily loop through the collection for the sum, using those I have the mean; but, I am not sure the most efficient way to get the mode.

I know I can find it if my data was in an array using Application.mode, but that doesn't appear to work for collections :(. Converting a collection to an array though to find the mode though really doesn't strike me as the most efficient solution. Only other option i can find of though is to sort the collections then loop through them to find the mode.

So wondering if anyone knows of a good way to find the statistical mode of a collection?

```
Dim locdata As Object
Set locdata = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")  

For counter = 2 To max
    mykey = Cells(counter, loccol).value
    If Not (locdata.exists(mykey)) Then
        locdata.Add (mykey), New Collection
    End If
    locdata(mykey).Add (Cells(counter, donamountcol).value)
Next counter
For Each k In locdata.keys
    locname = k
    Cells(counter, 1) = k
    Cells(counter, 2) = locdata(k).Count
    donationtotal = 0
    For Each donvalue In locdata(k)
        donationtotal = donationtotal + donvalue
    Next donvalue
    Cells(counter, 3) = donationtotal
    Cells(counter, 4) = donationtotal / CDbl(locdata(k).Count)
    'Cells(counter, 5) = Application.mode(locdata(k)) doesn't work :(
    counter = counter + 1
Next k
```

edit: Ideally the output should be (using Quebec as an example)
Quebec: Count: 10 Sum: 515 Average: 51.5 Mode: 50

Comment: Why not just use arrays in your dictionary instead of collections?  It may be easier to add things to a collection, but arrays would be simpler to calculate from...

Comment: I don't know how many values I would need to allocate to the array

Comment: You can use `ReDim Preserve myArray(newUpperBound)` to extend an array while preserving existing content.  Make sure to take the array out of the dictionary before you alter it though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404212/changing-array-values-in-a-vba-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just decided to make a dictionary of dictionaries. So I have the locations and each location than has a dictionary of the count of each donation amount. Was easy enough to compare counts that way to find the mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can have values in a range into aarray dynamically. And I would use **`CountIF`** in the VBA to find the most frequent objects by their names.. **Since you don't know the `location names` or the `donations`.** Then array is the way to go.

```
Dim ar as Variant
Dim endRow as Long

'get last row in the range
endRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
'ar = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Shets(1).Range("A1:A12")
 'using endrow
 ar = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Shets(1).Range("A1").resize(endRow).value)
```

UPDATE: The `subroutine` below uses one iteration (for loop) to find the `Mode`..

```
Sub FrequencyByLocDonations()
Dim ar As Variant, dc As Object
Dim rngInput As Range, mxRng As Range
Dim endRow As Long, i As Integer
Dim counts As Double, maxLoc As Double
Dim maxLocation As String
   Set dc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   '-- When you know the range
   '   ar = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Shets(1).Range("A1:A12").Value

    'get last row in the range when you don't know but the starting cell
    endRow = Sheets(3).Cells(Sheets(3).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngInput = Sheets(3).Range("C2").Resize(endRow - 1, 1)

    '--you may also use that set rngInput as well
    '   WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngInput).Value

    '-- using endrow-1 to not to take an extra blank row at the end
    ar = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(3).Range("C2").Resize(endRow - 1, 2).Value)

    For i = LBound(ar, 2) To UBound(ar, 2)
        If Not (dc.exists(ar(1, i))) Then
            counts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngInput, ar(1, i))
            If counts >= maxLoc Then
                maxLocation = ar(1, i)
                maxLoc = counts
            End If
            dc.Add ar(1, i), counts
        End If
    Next i

    '-- output to the Sheet
    Sheets(3).Range("C2").Offset(0, 2).Resize(UBound(dc.keys) + 1, 1) = _ 
              Application.Transpose(dc.keys)
    Sheets(3).Range("C2").Offset(0, 3).Resize(UBound(dc.items) + 1, 1) = _
              Application.Transpose(dc.items)
    Sheets(3).Range("C2").Offset(0, 4) = "Most Frequent Location :" _ 
              & maxLocation & "; " & maxLoc

    Set dc = Nothing
End Sub
```

output:

[image]

Comment: @Wizuriel This code might look longer. It's mainly due to the comments. :) Please give it a try and attached picture shows how the output works for `mode`..

Comment: Unfortunately I'm actually looking for the mode of the donations for each location (which looking at my data I should have chosen better numbers as none of them have a clear mode). using countif is a good idea though

Comment: @Wizuriel blimey! Well I read your question now ;-)  can you please update the donations column with numbers that make sense to your stats? Good news is it is possible to be done within my code and it will be just a few lines to change... I am out now and will update when I get back if I see your question is updated :-) Also please allocate the expected results set based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar situation in the past. It seemed to me there was a very powerful VBA function missing from excel - equivalent to the "where" statement in MySQL.
So I wrote a very simple one myself... This lacks a lot of functionality, but it will allow you to do what you are asking for, while minimizing the amount of code you write.
Fundamental concept: you can return an array from a function call, and Excel built-in functions can operate on such an array as they would on a function. Thus, if you have a function that returns "all the numbers of which I want the mode", then `=MODE(myfunction())` will give you the answer you want.
I chose to call my function `subset(criteria, range1, range2)`. 
In its most simple form it returns the elements in range2 that correspond to elements in range1 that meet criteria.
This is NOT extensively tested, but I hope you get the idea.
By the way, you can enter this as an array formula (shift-ctrl-enter) in multiple cells; in that case you get the first returned element in the first cell, etc. Sometimes that's a useful trick when you have a function that needs to return more than one value (e.g. a range) - but for this case you only need the result to feed to another function.

```
Option Explicit
' Function subset(criteria, range1, range2)
' Return an array with the elements in range2 that correspond to
' elements in range1 that match "criteria"
' where "criteria" can be a string, or a value with a < = > sign in front of it

' example: =subset("bravo", A1:A10, B1:B10)
' returns all cells from B that corresponds to cells in A with "bravo"
' =subset("<10", A1:A10, B1:B10) returns all cells in B corresponding to
' cells in A with a value < 10
' This is analogous to the "where" function in SQL, but much more primitive

Function subset(criteria As String, range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
Dim c
Dim result
Dim ii, jj As Integer
On Error GoTo etrap

If range1.Cells.Count <> range2.Cells.Count Then Exit Function
ReDim result(1 To range1.Cells.Count)
ii = 1
jj = 1
For Each c In range1.Cells
If compare(c.Value, criteria) = 0 Then
  result(ii) = range2.Cells(jj).Value
  ii = ii + 1
End If
jj = jj + 1
Next c

If ii > 1 Then
ReDim Preserve result(1 To ii - 1)
subset = result
Else
subset = Nothing
End If

Exit Function
etrap:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Description
End Function

Private Function compare(a, b)
' type of a decides what kind of comparison we do
If TypeName(a) <> TypeName("hello") Then
' use numerical comparison
compare = Not (Evaluate(a & b))
Else
' use string comparison
compare = StrComp(a, b, vbTextCompare)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: It seems to me I need to learn to read the question better... I guess this doesn't answer your need very well. Maybe my solution is still useful to someone, somewhere. For example, you could take the code I made to create an array of the elements you wanted, and then use application.mode() to get your answer. Unless your database is huge, this should work quite well. And if your database IS, in fact, huge, you should consider something other than Excel.

Comment: You can find an example spreadsheet that implements this method [here](ftp://www.floris.us/public_ftp/SOhelp2.xlsm)