# copying and sum cells with same value in a column

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need function or macro in excel to count cells with same data in a column:

```
mn3288a  
mn3088a  
mn3088a  
mn3088a  
mn3288a  
3009-3001  
LKE1  
LKE1  
LKE1  
mn3088a  
3001-3009
```

The result should be something like this:

```
mn3288a    2  
mn3088a    4  
3009-3001  2  
LKE1       3
```

in new sheet. So I need to copy one value and count repetition of that value in a column. The sheet with data is filed on daily basis, and there is about 25000 different values. I tried to combine `countifs, exat, if...` functions in excel, but without any progress. And I don't know much about macros. So any help, a hint would be great! Thanks

Comment: You can use a pivot table to do this.

Comment: It won't give me report. Thanks for formatting question.

Comment: Why did `countIf` not work for you?

Comment: I can't associate just cell in that function (A2 for example) but i need to manual insert value(s)

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost entirely sure either a pivot table or a `countif()` would work for you.  The pivot table would be easier.

Just create it and refresh it every day after you paste in the new data (or you can change the pivot table to automatically refresh when you open the file).

Comment: I think Ill be able to do something with pivot table, just to figure out how they work for sum number of repetitions. :-/But thanks again for hint

Comment: +1 @PowerUser ;) two nice tips.

Comment: @Pera, For your value in the pivot, you can Count your text field.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `countif` easily like how above answer from Poweruser has mentioned, when you know the list of the data.. When you do not know then you can use Pivot too.

- However in anycase if you plan to use VBA...(not recommended, but if you do) then give this a try :)

  [count by unknown column values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261584/vba-excel-finding-the-statistical-mode-of-a-collection/14262473#14262473)