# Extracting array from VBA dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I cannot find out how to store and access an array in a VBA dictionary.

I have a key with multiple items, say "Apple" with value "3" and quantity "5".

A single item would not be a problem, ie: dict("Apples") = 3

But how do I store and retrieve multiple values? Lets say I want to add "Apples, 3, 5" and then move to cell C4 and automatically paste Apples there, 3 in C5 and 5 in C6.

So far I've tried:

```
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim last_col As Long
last_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim strVal As String
Dim Item(0 To 99) As String
Dim header As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(1 + i, 1), Cells(last_row, 1))
    i = i + 1
    strVal = rngCell.Text
    If Not dict.Exists(strVal) Then
            n = 0
            For Each headerCell In Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, last_col))
                n = n + 1
                Item(n) = headerCell.Text
                'MsgBox headerCell.Text
            Next headerCell
            dict(strVal) = Item
    Else
        MsgBox "already exists"
    End If
Next rngCell

Dim Items(0 To 99) As String
sFruit = InputBox("Check value of key")
Items = dict(sFruit)
MsgBox "The value of " & sFruit & " is " & Items(2)
```

It's the last part that isn't working. Whether I declare Items as Variant or String or Object or even if I put Item = Items(2) above the message box and refer to that. I can't extract any kind of information out of an array retrieved from the dictionary. It seems that Items = dict(sFruit) is not the way to retrieve an array.

Comment: Exact duplicate of your previous question: [Referencing array in VBA dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772708/referencing-array-in-vba-dictionary). Edit your question to improve it then it can be re-opened, it was closed for a reason.

Comment: Hi Wolfie, it was edited but not reopened. Therefor I posted a new question.

Comment: You have to wait for it to be re-opened pending a review, depending whether or not your edit is sufficient

Comment: You only have a single array `Item` but you're adding it to every dictionary key's value?  It would help a lot to explain what your data is and what the code is supposed to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

If you dim `items` as variant, and use `array()` it should work.

This is just an example and not your code.

```
Sub testdict()
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dict.Add "apple", Array(1, 3)
    dict.Add "orange", Array(2, 5)

    Dim k As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vals As Variant
    For Each k In dict
        vals = dict(k) 'set a variant to an array
        Debug.Print vals(1) 'print the second element
        For i = LBound(dict(k)) To UBound(dict(k)) 'iterate through all array elements
            Debug.Print k, dict(k)(i) 'print everything in the dict
        Next i
    Next k

End Sub
```