# Why won't VBA array with in ArrayList ReDim inside a subrotine and preserve the scope?

Tags: arrays, vba

I am changing the size of the array inside an array list using ReDim in separate subroutine. But the array size isn't changing in the main subroutine. I am using ByRef. findItem checks if any items in one array exists in another array. The print out in the console is

```
In Change Array Size: 12
In combine Array Size: 6
In Change Array Size: 14
In combine Array Size: 7
```

Here is my code

```
Sub combineCRMITN(ByRef assocMap As Object, TN As Object, crmitnAbort As Date)
    Dim assocRow As Long, tnRow As Variant, assocSize As Long, TnStrCount As Long, assocSizeNew As Long, wholeSize As Long
    For assocRow = 0 To assocMap.Count - 1
        For Each tnRow In TN
            If findItem(assocMap.Item(assocRow), tnRow) Then
                TnStrCount = CountString(tnRow)
                assocSize = UBound(assocMap.Item(assocRow))
                Call changeSize(assocMap.Item(assocRow), assocSize)
                Debug.Print ("In combine Array Size: " & UBound(assocMap.Item(assocRow)))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next tnRow
        If Now > crmitnAbort Then Exit For
    Next assocRow
End Sub

Sub changeSize(ByRef theArray As Variant, newArrSize As Long)
    Dim theArraySize As Long
    theArraySize = UBound(theArray)
    ReDim theArray(theArraySize + newArrSize)
    Debug.Print ("In Change Array Size: " & UBound(theArray))
End Sub

Function findItem(arrRow1 As Variant, arrRow2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim arr1Size As Long, arr1ind As Long
    arr1Size = UBound(arrRow1)
    For arr1ind = 0 To arr1Size
        If IsIn(VarType(arrRow1(arr1ind)), "2,3,4,5") Then
            If IsInArray(CLng(arrRow1(arr1ind)), arrRow2) Then
                findItem = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next arr1ind
    findItem = False
End Function
```

The end result is the array size will change in the main function combineCRMITN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If assocMap is a scripting dictionary, you cannot modify an array that's stored in it: you have to first extract the array into a variable, then modify it, then replace it.

```vb
Dim tmp
'...
'...
tmp = assocMap.Item(assocRow)
changeSize tmp, assocSize
assocMap.Item(assocRow) = tmp
```

Same goes for arrays stored in a Collection. Eg:

```vb
Dim col As New Collection

col.Add Array(1)

Debug.Print col(1)(0) '1

col(1)(0) = 2

Debug.Print col(1)(0) 'still 1
```

Previously: [Changing array values in a VBA dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404212/changing-array-values-in-a-vba-dictionary)

EDIT-just noticed ArrayList in the title: same goes for that too...