# Aggregating records with two main IDs in [VBA macro]

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a macro in Excel that summarizes data from rows that match a composite ID generated from 2 ID columns. In my excel sheet, each row has 2 main ID columns: `ID_1` is the main key, and `ID_2` is a secondary key from which I only care about the first 2 letters (Which I have gotten using `LEFT`). I want to group rows with the same `ID_1` and first 2 letters of `ID_2` and report the `SUM` of the `value`, `count`, and `sum` columns.

In the example picture below, I want to turn the data in columns `A:J` into the data in columns `M:V`

So, with this example -> We have 6 records **1015** (ID_1) with 3 different ID_2 (**AB**, **AZ**, **AE**). I want to sum them up to a one cell each (**1015 AB** ; **1015 AZ** ;**1015 AE**) with values which each record had (there is 3 records: **1015 AB** with VALUE of 2,3,4 so in result I want to get just one row **1015 AB** **9**(sum of *value*) **4**(sum of *count*) **17** (sum of(*value* * *count*)). It's important to see that this **17** dosn't come from **9 * 4**. It's =sum(I4:I6) (but it may be spread out like in **1200 FF** example below! I am still trying to sort them both at one time, but I cant get past it..)

[image]

Comment: To make **what** faster? I don't see anything to make 'faster'.

Comment: As you can see, images on the Web aren't guaranteed to load (nice useless alt text btw). **Paste** the *actual code* in the post, select it, then hit Ctrl+K to automatically add the 4-space indent to all lines, making it format as code. If that image wasn't your code, ...[edit] your post to include the code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column in D to combine the ID_1 and the first 2 characters of ID_2. `=A4 & LEFT(C4,2)`. Copy that down then go to L4 and type in:

```
=+INDEX($D$4:$D$25,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(L$3:L3,$D$4:$D$25),0)
```

and hold down `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to make it an array function. Copy down to get a list of unique combinations, and then split these values into the separate columns.

Finally to pull in the numbers, put this in Q4:

```
=SUMIFS(E$4:E$25,$A$4:$A$25,M4,$C$4:$C$25,O4 & "*")
```

and then copy down and across.

Comment: It looks nice, I did think about it in this way, but main problem was that how to make a columns in M and O with data which you see in example. Macro or formula which will see that there is in column C three different ID_2 with same ID_1 from column A and "stack" them together elsewhere in sheet.

Comment: Oh. How often do these values change? Would there be different combinations of ID_1 and ID_2 every time the sheet is updated, or would these be pretty stable and only change occasionally? 
If they change pretty often, then I probably would use a macro to collect all the ID_1-ID_2-prefix combinations as keys in a Scripting Dictionary object, and an array of the numbers as a value such as in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656580/create-dictionary-of-lists-in-vba)

Comment: There will be new combinations every time there is a new Excel. I will check your suggestion. :)

Comment: And also there will be a different number of records with every Excel. On one case there can be 100 records, on next one there can be 10000 records.

Comment: I guess that I found pretty good answer. I will sum up ID_1 and ID_2 in column L, then I will check something like "first occurrence" of every record in this column, then I will split them again in ID_1 and ID_2 from columns M and O.

Comment: Yes! That's a great idea. And you can use an array function to extract the unique combinations. If you put the combined ID_1 and ID_2 in column K, you can go to L4 and type in +INDEX($A$4:$A$25,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(L$3:L3,$A$4:$A$25),0)) and hold down Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula. Then copy the cell down and it will give you a list of unique values.